# Cannot update during render, on Image onError function

Tags: javascript, react-native

I just got `warning` about cannot update during render. It's recommend me to update on `ComponentWillMount`. But I change the state after checking if the image is `Error (not Loaded)`, so I must change state on render function.

```
  _onError = (index) => {
    let data = this.state.data;
    if (data[index].imageError === false) {
      data[index].imageError = true;
      this.setState({ data: data });
    }
  }

render() {
   this.state.data.map((n, index) => {
      <Image
         source={
            n.imageError
            ? rightImg
            : {
               uri: `${notRightImg}`
               }
          }
          style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }}
          onError={this._onError(index)}
        />
   })
}
```

Comment: Try changing `onError={this._onError(index)}` to `onError={() => this._onError(index)}`

Comment: still same, the warning still showing

Answer (score 0):

The reference of `this.state.data` not changed in function `onError`. You can try to use:

```
this.setState({ data: [...data] });
```

to replace:

```
this.setState({ data: data });
```